# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (using Rest API, JDK 7 in oracle cloud)

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using REST API for fetching list of compartments. When i use JDK 8, i am getting the response and when i switch to JDK 7, getting the handshake failure error.

I used as per the sample code mentioned here [Signing](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm#Java)  in Java 8. After that, since my project uses java 7, i rewrote the code in java 7. But getting the below exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
```

I am looking onto this for 2 days but no luck. Any inputs?

Comment: Probably something to do with the SSL / TLS versions or cipher suites supported.  The linked Q&A explains how to debug this.

Comment: A better solution is to NOT use Java 7.  It is end-of-life!